# How to extend polygon by a certain distance in PHP/Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, polygon, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a location defined by a polygon (e.g.(-8.87 41.86,-8.74 41.98,-8.63 42.06,-8.16 42.13 ...) ) and want to search for places from db within the polygon extended by a distance.

Google maps algorithm: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_ConvexHull_extend.asp

Any idea how to get extended polygon in PHP/MySQL in order to search for records from MySQL? I use ST_CONTAINS mysql function to search for records within an exact polygon.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_%28geometry%29

Comment: Is there only one polygon and is it fixed?

Comment: This sounds like a GIS problem.

Comment: @davidstrachan hundreds of polygons

Comment: Looks like a buffer with mitre joins. You might be able to do this with [GeoPHP](https://geophp.net/geos.html), but I've not used it. This functionality is in GEOS, PostGIS, JTS and others.